# Unable to launch JWrapper under MacOS High Sierra

Tags: jwrapper, macos-high-sierra

We have an application that, up until today's High Sierra update, was running fine under MacOS.  Now it will update, but not run the application.

We also note that JWrapper.app also doesn't run under High Sierra.

Here is a log snippet - does anyone have a clue as to what is wrong?

```
...
+0    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+0    +++ Start: Launching
+0    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+0    [Extractor] Launching 'JWrapper-JWrapper-00049034758-complete' from master folder '/Users/user/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-APPNAME (UAT)' of class 0 using JRE 'Mac64JRE'
+1    [PickFolder] Folder JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00054617449-complete.plugin matches Mac64JRE with version 54617449
+0    [PickFolder] Set latest to 54617449 JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00054617449-complete.plugin
+0    [PickFolder] Folder JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00054617449-complete matches Mac64JRE with version 54617449
+0    [Extractor] Using private JRE JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00054617449-complete.plugin
+0    [Utils] File does NOT exist: /Users/user/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-APPNAME (UAT)/JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00054617449-complete.plugin/bin/APPNAME (UAT)
+0    [Extractor] Copying FILE /Users/user/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-APPNAME (UAT)/JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00054617449-complete.plugin/bin/APPNAME (UAT)
+0    [Extractor] *************************** Unable to open source file for copy /Users/user/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-APPNAME (UAT)/JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00054617449-complete.plugin/bin/java
+0    *******************************************
+0    Error setting app binary executable!
+0    *******************************************
+0    [Extractor] JRE LSO file is /Users/user/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-APPNAME (UAT)/JWApps/JRE-LastSuccessfulOptions-JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00054617449-complete.plugin
+0    [Extractor] Building classpath
+0    [Extractor] Creating launch properties
+0    [Extractor] Checking LSO file
+0    [Extractor] Reading /Users/user/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-APPNAME (UAT)/JWApps/JRE-LastSuccessfulOptions-JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00054617449-complete.plugin
+0    [Utils] File does NOT exist: /Users/user/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-APPNAME (UAT)/JWApps/JRE-LastSuccessfulOptions-JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00054617449-complete.plugin
+0    *******************************************
+0    JRE LSO file does not exist
+0    *******************************************
+0    [Extractor] Writing launch properties file
+0    [Extractor] Writing launch properties to /Users/user/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-APPNAME (UAT)/JWrapper-JWrapper-00049034758-complete/JWLaunchProperties-1506477183962-19
+0    [Extractor] Launch properties length is 868
+0    [Extractor] Writing to file
+1    [Extractor] Finished writing launch properties file
+0    [Extractor] Reading 0 extra args
+0    [Extractor] Read JRE compatibility class jwrapper.updater.GenericUpdaterJreVerifierLaunch
+0    [Extractor] Appending 1 command line args
+0    [Extractor] Executable: /Users/user/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-APPNAME (UAT)/JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00054617449-complete.plugin/bin/APPNAME (UAT)
+0    [Extractor] Argument 0: /Users/user/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-APPNAME (UAT)/JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00054617449-complete.plugin/bin/APPNAME (UAT)
+0    [Extractor] Argument 1: -cp
+0    [Extractor] Argument 2: /Users/user/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-APPNAME (UAT)/JWrapper-JWrapper-00049034758-complete/jwrapperlib/jwstandalonelaunch.jar
+0    [Extractor] Argument 3: jwrapper.updater.GenericUpdaterLaunch
+0    [Extractor] Argument 4: /Users/user/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-APPNAME (UAT)/JWrapper-JWrapper-00049034758-complete/JWLaunchProperties-1506477183962-19
+0    [Extractor] Argument 5: -psn_0_2048500
+0    [Extractor] This is a newer extractor... launchclass is 0
+0    [Extractor] JRE folder is /Users/user/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-APPNAME (UAT)/JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00054617449-complete.plugin
+0    [BundleLoader] Creating jre path URL for path /Users/user/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-APPNAME (UAT)/JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00054617449-complete.plugin.plugin
+0    [BundleLoader] Created NSURL
+0    [BundleLoader] Bundle is null?+0    [Extractor] Adjusted JRE folder is /Users/user/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-APPNAME (UAT)/JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00054617449-complete.plugin.plugin/Contents/Home
+0    [Extractor] Force spawn is 0 so attempting to launch via JNI
+0    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+0    +++ Start: JNI Launch
+0    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+0    [JNILaunch] [pid=9416] [mainThread=0]
+0    [JNILaunch] [ERROR] Could not load dynamic library!
+0    [JNILaunch] [ERROR] Unable to load JRE library!
+0    [Extractor] Return code for JNI launch was 1
+0    ------------------------------------------------
+0    --- End: JNI Launch
+0    ------------------------------------------------
+0    [Extractor] JNI launch failed. Attempting legacy spawn instead
+0    [Extractor] Attempting spawn launch
+0    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+0    +++ Start: Spawn launch
+0    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+0    [Utils] Closing logging file.
```

Comment: Ok, I'll have to retract my comment about JWrapper.app not running.  The latest version does.  Some hints there, I think.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is simple - update the JRE to the latest Oracle JRE, which at time of writing was 1.8.0_144.

We note that the jwrapper version we are using (49034758) is the latest version you can run without purchasing a license.  I would seriously think twice before paying for this product.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will try to see if this works with my  jwrapper-00044250826.jar, any idea where I could download 49034758, they have removed all the links from their website. I like the product (except no support for file associations) but I've never felt comfortable with the company, no answers, no support for the free/small developers. They say they they monitor and use SO for support, not much evidence for that. Time to move on I guess. javafxpackager works but requires packaging on each platform which is a nuisance.

Comment: I've since had it fail using the latest JRE as well.  It's a random chance whether or not it will install or update, but it seems to be Gatekeeper in MacOS is preventing the updater from downloading or marking files as executable.  Are you signing your application with an Apple Dev key?  I wonder if that has an effect.

Comment: A general note to the developers of this product, who claim they're watching on SO:  Basically, we'll keep using the last free version until it stops working on Windows.  After that we'll move to another product that doesn't treat their clients like garbage.  We don't mind paying for software, but your price, and the level of support offered at that price, is laughable.

Comment: Hi Mark.  We don’t claim to be watching SO for support and haven’t made that claim for a long time.  We removed the free version of JWrapper and now offer support only to customers because its not feasible for us to support free users of JWrapper.  When we created JWrapper we hoped to provide the Java community with something that has been missing for a long time but unfortunately the free version has not been as popular as we would have liked and Java developers that require support typically have complex queries that are time consuming (expensive) to resolve.

Comment: This issue is caused by the macOS upgrade to APFS.  It is resolved in the latest version of JWrapper but as you have pointed out it is not available for free.

Comment: Hi Antony.  So, if we'd spent 3k on a license just over a year ago with the 30 days support, and this issue had come up, we'd be up for another 3K to resolve it, not to mention having to pay to diagnose the issue,  am I right?  That's my reading of your license terms, anyhow.  And if we'd stumped up the 4K for the full year's support, we'd be equally hosed with regard to updates.  This is what I'm talking about when I say you treat your customers like garbage.  We don't mind paying for software, but this feels like being ripped off.

Comment: Hi Mark.  No company can absorb the ongoing cost of new versions indefinitely while charging a fixed cost, it is just not sustainable.  The team license covers an entire development team for one year so any new version or fixes released within 12 months you would have access to.  At an individual level that may seem expensive but the equivalent per developer per year for e.g. 10 devs is far cheaper than many of our competitors that charge thousands per workstation or server and we are up front about how the licenses work and the cost.

Comment: You have just made the most powerful argument possible for open source software.  Thank you.

Comment: @AntonyM I think the product functionality (lack of file association not withstanding) was great. Something that the Java community really lacked and needed. Too bad it does not make sense for you to continue the free version ... perhaps it was the lack Freedom that made your excellent stuff less popular than what it deserved. But hard to make money on free software. Alas I'm moving to javafxpackager even if it is more work, your pricing model does not work for me. It was great while it lasted, thanks.